# Sum with awk substr function- Linux Commands

Tags: linux, bash, awk

Is there a way I can write commands to do the following logic to get the count of:

B records and
sum of T records based on the value in subStr($0, 2, 10)

Note subStr($0, 1, 1) defines the Record Type- A, B or T.

Here is a sample text file.

```
A 000000001 201903 ABC    
B201901JOHN 000000006    
B201901KUHN 000000007    
T00000002B00000000I    
A 000000002 201903 CBA    
B201901BONN 000000008    
B201901BERN 000000009    
B201901HULA 000000009    
T00000003{00000000I
```

Expected Output:

### 1

Do until the end of the file:

```
If substr($0,1,1) = "B" Then 
    bCount=bCount+1

Else If left($0,1,1) = "T" Then 

    tCount=substr($0,2,9)*10 

    Select Case substr($0,10,1) 

        Case "{" tCount=tCount+0 

        Case "A" tCount=tCount+0 

        Case "B" tCount=tCount+0 

        Case "C" tCount=tCount+0 

        Case "D" tCount=tCount+0 

        Case "K" tCount=(tCount+1) * -1

        Case "L" tCount=(tCount+2) * -1 

        Case "}" tCount=(tCount+0) * -1 

        End Select

End If
```

---

What I have so far is command to count the number of records that are starting with "B"

```
egrep -o file1.txt | wc -l > BRecCount.txt
```

I am not sure how to get the sum of the T records based on the value of position [2 to 10] for each of the T records.

And then combine the commands and see if B records count and T records total is equal then return 0 else return 1.

Comment: the 10th characters in the `T` strings are `B` and `{` ... ?? please update the question to clarify where the `T` values are coming from; also, please update the question with the output generated by your code as well as the expected output (corresponding to the samlpe input)

Comment: what are `left()`, `mid()` and `Mid()`? please update the question with your response

Comment: what language are you attempting to code in?  you've tagged the question with `bash` and `awk` but this code is not valid syntax in `bash` nor `awk` ... ???

Comment: This script was written in Microsoft Visual Basic  achieving SSIS script task. And I am trying to achieve this task with linux command.

Answer (score 0):

That was so straightforward (IMHO, we'll see) that I couldn't resist myself:

```
$ awk '{
    if(substr($0,1,1) == "B")
        bCount=bCount+1
    else if(substr($0,1,1) == "T") {
        tCount=substr($0,2,9)*10
        switch(substr($0,10,1)) {
            case "{":
                tCount=tCount+0;
                break
            case "A":
                tCount=tCount+0
                break
            case "B":
                tCount=tCount+0
                break
            case "C":
                tCount=tCount+0
                break
            case "D":
                tCount=tCount+0
                break
            case "K":
                tCount=(tCount+1) * -1
                break
            case "L":
                tCount=(tCount+2) * -1
                break
            case "}":
                tCount=(tCount+0) * -1
                break
        }
    }
}
END {
    exit bCount!=tCount
}' file; echo $?
```